# Ktor websocket client do not send message

Tags: kotlin, websocket, server, client, ktor

Ktor websocket client do not send handshake message. The response from the client is not sent to the server.

my code client

```
override fun <T> connect(url: String, serializer: KSerializer<*>, action: (T) -> Unit) {
        println("Началось подключение websocketHost")

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            
            client.webSocket(method = HttpMethod.Get, host = "localhost", port = 8080, path = "/$url") {

                println("Произошло подключение /${url}. Началась отправка первого сообщения")

                //sendFirstMessage()
                val webSocketFirstMessage = getFirstMessage()
                val str = Json.encodeToString(WebSocketFirstMessage.serializer(), webSocketFirstMessage)
                println(str)
                try {
                    send("hello")
                    println("Первое сообщение отправлено")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("Первое сообщение НЕ отправлено, по причине: ${e.message}\n${e.stackTraceToString()}")
                }

            }
             
        }

    }
```

The error refers to the send() method. When checking "outgoing.isClosedForSpeed" says that "true". The connection is established, but for some reason the channel for sending is closed.
Outputs the following error in log on send function

`Первое сообщение НЕ отправлено, по причине: Unexpected receiver type: <S_RESUMING_BY_RCV> IllegalStateException: Unexpected receiver type: <S_RESUMING_BY_RCV> at Object.captureStack (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:39915:15) at IllegalStateException.Exception [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:40254:14) at IllegalStateException.RuntimeException [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:40280:17) at IllegalStateException [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:40320:24) at IllegalStateException_init_0 (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:40331:29) at BufferedChannel.tryResumeReceiver_0 (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlinx-coroutines-core.js:6582:11) at BufferedChannel.updateCellSendSlow_0 (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlinx-coroutines-core.js:6543:16) at BufferedChannel.updateCellSend_0 (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlinx-coroutines-core.js:6475:17) at Coroutine$send_11rb$_0.doResume (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlinx-coroutines-core.js:5985:28) at BufferedChannel.send_11rb$ (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlinx-coroutines-core.js:6064:21)`

wanted println("Первое сообщение отправлено")
but writing println("Первое сообщение НЕ отправлено, по причине: ${e.message}\n${e.stackTraceToString()}")

Comment: Can you determine what line causes the `IllegalStateException: Unexpected receiver type` error?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman The error refers to the send() method. When checking "outgoing.isClosedForSpeed" says that "true". The connection is established, but for some reason the channel for sending is closed.

Comment: Can you try replacing the line `send("hello")` with `outgoing.send(Frame.Text("hello"))`?

Comment: @АлексейТирман I tried - the same thing happens, it doesn't work. The outgoing channel is closed. With error Unexpected receiver type: <S_RESUMING_BY_RCV>

Comment: Can you reproduce the same problem on the JVM platform?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Everything works well on the jvm

Comment: Can you please file an issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTOR) with a sample for the reproduction attached?